# scapy WARNING: can't import layer inet: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP

Tags: python, windows-7, scapy

I am using scapy with python 2.6.3 on windows 7 
When I enter, I get a list of warnings, some less important but some like this
"WARNING: can't import layer inet: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP"
when I try to send or receive packets I get errors.
I installed following instructions and downloading files from
http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#windows

Can someone help me figure out what I can do to fix this bug?

Comment: Please post the exact error messages you are seeing, not messages "like" them.

Comment: this is the exact screen messageWARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
WARNING: can't import layer inet: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP
'
WARNING: can't import layer dhcp: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP
'
WARNING: can't import layer dns: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP'

INFO: Can't import python Crypto lib. Won't be able to decrypt WEP.
WARNING: can't import layer gprs: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP
'
WARNING: can't import layer hsrp: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP
'
2 more warnings

Answer (score 1):

Trouble in using constant "**socket.IPPROTO_IPIP**", which is not implemented in this version of Python 2.
Look in file "**scapy/layers/inet6.py**", edit last string:

```
bind_layers(IPv6,      IP,       nh = socket.IPPROTO_IPIP )
```

replace with:

```
bind_layers(IPv6,      IP,       nh = 4 )
```

and delete inet6.pyc

[Proof from IP protocol numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers)
4   0x04    IP-in-IP    IP in IP (encapsulation)    RFC 2003

Comment: Honest to god, I didn't believe anyone could solve the problem and you did. Thank you soooo much